# oracle 8 convert char to long/blob

Tags: string, oracle, char, blob, long-integer

I am trying to convert string to long in oracle 8. How do I do that? I have only version from blob to char.

```
    function lob2char(clob_col clob) return varchar2 IS
buffer varchar2(4000);
amt BINARY_INTEGER := 4000;
pos INTEGER := 1;
l clob;
bfils bfile;
l_var varchar2(4000):='';
begin
LOOP
if dbms_lob.getlength(clob_col)<=4000 THEN
dbms_lob.read (clob_col, amt, pos, buffer);
l_var := l_var||buffer;
pos:=pos+amt;
ELSE
l_var:= 'Cannot convert.  Exceeded varchar2 limit';
exit;
END IF;
END LOOP;
return l_var;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
return l_var;
END;
```

Cannot find anywhere on google.

Comment: Why do you have a column of LONG datatype?
LONG datatype has been deprecated since CLOB's were introduced about 10 years ago. Oracle doesn't recommend you use LONG datatype's and it's only there to support backward compatibility.
I just did a search on google for "Oracle convert long to clob" and got loads of hits...

Comment: @Rene - they're still on 8i, which introduced LOBs if I recall correctly, and you're surprised they're still using LONG? Seems like the least of their problems... *8-) I don't think they were officially desupported then, but migration was already encouraged.

Comment: Where is your string coming from - is it already a `varchar2`? What's wrong with just assigning the string value to the `long` variable or column? The code you show seems to be irrelevant, and it really isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Its there, its an old system and I cannot change it, and I have varchar (string) and I need to store it to that column (type long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're just over-thinking this. A `varchar2` is always going to be smaller than a `long` or `clob` could be, so you can just assign your value. It's going the other way that causes problems. You can just do this in SQL:

```
insert into t42 (long_val, clob_val)
values ('any string up to 4000 chars', 'any other string up to 4000 chars');
```

Or from PL/SQL:

```
declare
  char_val varchar2(4000);
begin
  char_val := 'another string';
  insert into t42 (long_val, clob_val)
  values (char_val, char_val);
end;
/
```

[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be9d5/1) demo. I believe that all worked the same in 8i as it does now in 11g.

The PL/SQL `varchar2` can be up to 32k and still be inserted like this.

Comment: Yes, I was over-thinking. I used utl_raw.cast_to_raw('...') and it worked.

Comment: @babboon - you're putting character data into a `blob`? Why? You should be using `clob` for character data?